# Problem using VariantDir with a SCons Builder that generates a list of files to use as source for Program

Tags: c++, antlr4, scons

I have a SConstruct that build my tool in 3 steps:

1. build a static library. In my case it's the antlr4 c++ runtime
2. generate the antlr4 cpp and h files (listener, visitor etc) of an antlr4's grammar
3. finally build a program using those files and linking to the antlr4 runtime library.

1 and 2 can be built in any order, even together but 3 ahs to be built when the other two have finished.
All this works perfectly when I don't use any VariantDir, however SCons fails when I try to use a variant directory, saying that it can't find the autogenerated files:

```
cons: *** [build/Parser/CoralBaseListener.o] Source `build/Parser/CoralBaseListener.cpp' not found, needed by target `build/Parser/CoralBaseListener.o'.
```

this is the whole SConstruct:

```
import os
import subprocess


env = Environment(
    CC = "clang",
    CXX = "clang++",
    CXXFLAGS = ['-std=c++11', '-stdlib=libc++']
)

env.Append(ENV = {'CLASSPATH': './dependencies/antlr4/antlr-4.8-complete.jar'})

# RelWithDbgInfo
env.Append(CXXFLAGS = ['-O2', '-g', '-DNDEBUG'])

VariantDir('./build', './src')
VariantDir('./build/antlr4Runtime', './dependencies/antlr4Runtime')

#
# Builder for generating grammar files with antlr4 (the java app)
#

def auto_antlr_generated_files(prefix):
    return [File(prefix + _file + ext) for _file in [
        'CoralBaseListener',
        'CoralBaseVisitor',
        'CoralLexer',
        'CoralListener',
        'CoralParser',
        'CoralVisitor'] for ext in ['.cpp', '.h']
    ]

def antlr_emitter(target, source, env):
    target = auto_antlr_generated_files('src/Parser/')
    return target, source


AntlrBuilder = Builder(
    action='java org.antlr.v4.Tool $SOURCE -Dlanguage=Cpp -package Coral -visitor -listener -o src/Parser',
    emitter=antlr_emitter
)

env.Append(BUILDERS={'Antlr': AntlrBuilder})

#
# Cloning the Environment for Antlr4 runtime
#

antlrEnv = env.Clone()

antlrEnv.Append(CXXFLAGS = [
    '-Wall',
    '-pedantic',
    '-W',
    '-Wno-overloaded-virtual',
    '-Wno-dollar-in-identifier-extension',
    '-Wno-four-char-constants'
])

#
# Building in 3 steps, first the antlr4 runtime library, then the parser files with Antlr then the final program
#

AntlrRuntime = antlrEnv.StaticLibrary(
                            'lib/antlr4-runtime',
                            source = 
                                Glob('./build/antlr4Runtime/*.cpp') + \
                                Glob('./build/antlr4Runtime/atn/*.cpp') + \
                                Glob('./build/antlr4Runtime/dfa/*.cpp') + \
                                Glob('./build/antlr4Runtime/misc/*.cpp') + \
                                Glob('./build/antlr4Runtime/support/*.cpp') + \
                                Glob('./build/antlr4Runtime/tree/*.cpp') + \
                                Glob('./build/antlr4Runtime/tree/pattern/*.cpp') + \
                                Glob('./build/antlr4Runtime/tree/xpath/*.cpp'),
                            CPPPATH = './build/antlr4Runtime',
                            ARFLAGS = 'qc'
                          )

ParserFiles = env.Antlr(source='./Coral.g4')

CoralLang = env.Program(target   = 'coral', 
                        source   = Glob('./build/*.cpp') + Glob('./build/Parser/*.cpp'), 
                        CPPPATH  = ['./build', './build/antlr4Runtime'],
                        LIBPATH  = './lib',
                        LIBS     = ['antlr4-runtime']
                        )



Requires(ParserFiles, AntlrRuntime)
Depends(auto_antlr_generated_files('./build/src/Parser/'), ParserFiles)
Depends(CoralLang, ParserFiles)
```

It is probably worth mentioning that at this point, when I have the error, the autogenerated antlr4 files are not in ./src nor in ./build, So basically the command never generated them in first place.

note that without VariantDir everything works as expected. Everything is build in the right steps without problems

```
import os
import subprocess


env = Environment(
    CC = "clang",
    CXX = "clang++",
    CXXFLAGS = ['-std=c++11', '-stdlib=libc++']
)

env.Append(ENV = {'CLASSPATH': './dependencies/antlr4/antlr-4.8-complete.jar'})

# RelWithDbgInfo
env.Append(CXXFLAGS = ['-O2', '-g', '-DNDEBUG'])

#
# Builder for generating grammar files with antlr4 (the java app)
#

def auto_antlr_generated_files(prefix):
    return [File(prefix + _file + ext) for _file in [
        'CoralBaseListener',
        'CoralBaseVisitor',
        'CoralLexer',
        'CoralListener',
        'CoralParser',
        'CoralVisitor'] for ext in ['.cpp', '.h']
    ]

def antlr_emitter(target, source, env):
    target = auto_antlr_generated_files('src/Parser/')
    return target, source


AntlrBuilder = Builder(
    action='java org.antlr.v4.Tool $SOURCE -Dlanguage=Cpp -package Coral -visitor -listener -o src/Parser',
    emitter=antlr_emitter
)

env.Append(BUILDERS={'Antlr': AntlrBuilder})

#
# Cloning the Environment for Antlr4 runtime
#

antlrEnv = env.Clone()

antlrEnv.Append(CXXFLAGS = [
    '-Wall',
    '-pedantic',
    '-W',
    '-Wno-overloaded-virtual',
    '-Wno-dollar-in-identifier-extension',
    '-Wno-four-char-constants'
])

#
# Building in 3 steps, first the antlr4 runtime library, then the parser files with Antlr then the final program
#

AntlrRuntime = antlrEnv.StaticLibrary(
                            'lib/antlr4-runtime',
                            source = 
                                Glob('./dependencies/antlr4Runtime/*.cpp') + \
                                Glob('./dependencies/antlr4Runtime/atn/*.cpp') + \
                                Glob('./dependencies/antlr4Runtime/dfa/*.cpp') + \
                                Glob('./dependencies/antlr4Runtime/misc/*.cpp') + \
                                Glob('./dependencies/antlr4Runtime/support/*.cpp') + \
                                Glob('./dependencies/antlr4Runtime/tree/*.cpp') + \
                                Glob('./dependencies/antlr4Runtime/tree/pattern/*.cpp') + \
                                Glob('./dependencies/antlr4Runtime/tree/xpath/*.cpp'),
                            CPPPATH = './dependencies/antlr4Runtime',
                            ARFLAGS = 'qc'
                          )

ParserFiles = env.Antlr(source='./Coral.g4')

CoralLang = env.Program(target   = 'coral', 
                        source   = Glob('./src/*.cpp') + Glob('./src/Parser/*.cpp'), 
                        CPPPATH  = ['./src', './dependencies/antlr4Runtime'],
                        LIBPATH  = './lib',
                        LIBS     = ['antlr4-runtime']
                        )

Requires(ParserFiles, AntlrRuntime)
Depends(CoralLang, ParserFiles)
```

I have the feeling that I'm doing something remarkably silly but I can't figure out what exactly.

This is what SCons output with the first SConstruct, the one that uses VariantDir:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: *** [build/Parser/CoralBaseListener.o] Source `build/Parser/CoralBaseListener.cpp' not found, needed by target `build/Parser/CoralBaseListener.o'.
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

This is really all and if I read this correctly, SCons is jumping straight to point 3 and of course at it fails because point 2 didn't create the files that point 3 needs as source.

This is instead a snippet of the output of the second SConstruct, the one that doesn't use VariantDir. (I cut off some of the similar lines where Scons create the static library, but they are all similar, as you know)

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
clang++ -o dependencies/antlr4Runtime/ANTLRErrorListener.o -c -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -Wall -pedantic -W -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-dollar-in-identifier-extension -Wno-four-char-constants -Idependencies/antlr4Runtime dependencies/antlr4Runtime/ANTLRErrorListener.cpp
...
clang++ -o dependencies/antlr4Runtime/tree/xpath/XPathWildcardElement.o -c -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -Wall -pedantic -W -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-dollar-in-identifier-extension -Wno-four-char-constants -Idependencies/antlr4Runtime dependencies/antlr4Runtime/tree/xpath/XPathWildcardElement.cpp
ar qc lib/libantlr4-runtime.a dependencies/antlr4Runtime/ANTLRErrorListener.o ... dependencies/antlr4Runtime/tree/xpath/XPathWildcardElement.o
ranlib lib/libantlr4-runtime.a
java org.antlr.v4.Tool Coral.g4 -Dlanguage=Cpp -package Coral -visitor -listener -o src/Parser
clang++ -o src/Parser/CoralListener.o -c -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -Isrc -Idependencies/antlr4Runtime src/Parser/CoralListener.cpp
clang++ -o src/Parser/CoralBaseListener.o -c -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -Isrc -Idependencies/antlr4Runtime src/Parser/CoralBaseListener.cpp
clang++ -o src/Parser/CoralParser.o -c -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -Isrc -Idependencies/antlr4Runtime src/Parser/CoralParser.cpp
clang++ -o src/Parser/CoralLexer.o -c -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -Isrc -Idependencies/antlr4Runtime src/Parser/CoralLexer.cpp
clang++ -o src/main.o -c -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -Isrc -Idependencies/antlr4Runtime src/main.cpp
clang++ -o src/Parser/CoralVisitor.o -c -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -Isrc -Idependencies/antlr4Runtime src/Parser/CoralVisitor.cpp
clang++ -o src/Parser/CoralBaseVisitor.o -c -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -Isrc -Idependencies/antlr4Runtime src/Parser/CoralBaseVisitor.cpp
clang++ -o coral src/main.o src/Parser/CoralBaseListener.o src/Parser/CoralBaseVisitor.o src/Parser/CoralLexer.o src/Parser/CoralListener.o src/Parser/CoralParser.o src/Parser/CoralVisitor.o -Llib -lantlr4-runtime
scons: done building targets.
```

So reading this is obvious that Scons start with building the static library, then he runs antlr to generate the files needed to parse my syntax and finally, when all the dependencies are created, it build the program.

Comment: Please either paste or pastebin your complete build log. need more info.

Comment: @bdbaddog I added the logs. As you can see though, Scons fails pretty much immediately.

Comment: your emitter function is passing `src/Parser` as the path but you're trying to operate in `build`?

Comment: @mats-wichmann that emitter is for the builder that will use antlr4 to generate cpp and h files to be compiled as part of the final program, which is in src. If this doesn't make sense, please explain why. This is the whole point of this website isn't it?

Comment: If you use VariantDir, your program is _not_ in src, it's in the VariantDir (scons makes sure that files "appear" there from src, but the build all happens in the variant). So I wonder when you have a function that's producing pathnames to generated files in src... and then your error immediately says `build/Parser/CoralBaseListener.cpp` is missing. I'm not saying that's "the" problem, I can't test it, but I'm wondering...

Comment: Agreed. The emitter is just odd. Use the target to find the directory?  Also same note about using Glob('./src')..

Comment: @MatsWichmann. Ok, I see your point. I don't have any special requirement except I'd like to be able to generate those antlr4 files in src and then, do the compilation in a variant.
I am, obviously, a novice in SCons and I will accept any modification to my SConstruct, it doesn't have to be like it is. If it isn't possible or even not desirable, I will take also a NO as a valid answer.

Comment: When you use VariantDir()s scons expects that no new files will be written to the source of the variantdir during the build. As the purpose of the variantdir is pretty much to not generate any files into the source dir. So as such you're bound to have problems this way.  Generate any files into your VariantDir, or some dir which is not the src of the variant dir.